# AWS DynamoDBMapper save method keeps throwing `DynamoDBMappingException: not supported; requires @DynamoDBTyped or @DynamoDBTypeConverted`

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, amazon-dynamodb

I followed everything that is outlined here - https://github.com/derjust/spring-data-dynamodb/wiki/Use-Hash-Range-keys. But still no luck.

I have a DynamoDB table with a hash key and a sort key.

Here is my entity class `RecentlyPlayed.class`

```
@DynamoDBTable(tableName="some-table")
public class RecentlyPlayed {

@Id
private RecentlyPlayedId recentlyPlayedId;

// ----- Constructor methods -----

@DynamoDBHashKey(attributeName="keyA")
// Getter and setter

@DynamoDBRangeKey(attributeName="keyB")
// Getter and setter

}
```

Here is my key class `RecentlyPlayedId.class`

```
public class RecentlyPlayedId implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String keyA;

    private String keyB;

    public RecentlyPlayedId(String keyA, String keyB) {
        this.keyA = keyA;
        this.keyB = keyB;
    }

    @DynamoDBHashKey
    // Getter and setter

    @DynamoDBRangeKey
    // Getter and setter
}
```

Here is my repository interface `RecentlyPlayedRepository`

```
@EnableScan
public interface RecentlyPlayedRepository extends CrudRepository<RecentlyPlayed, RecentlyPlayedId> {

    List<RecentlyPlayed> findAllByKeyA(@Param("keyA") String keyA);

    // Finding the entry for keyA with highest keyB
    RecentlyPlayed findTop1ByKeyAOrderByKeyBDesc(@Param("keyA") String keyA);
}
```

I am trying to save an object like this

```
RecentlyPlayed rp = new RecentlyPlayed(...);

dynamoDBMapper.save(rp);    // Throws that error

recentlyPlayedRepository.save(rp);  // Also throws the same error
```

I am using `Spring v2.0.1.RELEASE`. The wiki in the original docs warns about this error and describes what to do to mitigate. I did exactly what they said. But still no luck.

The link to that wiki is here - https://github.com/derjust/spring-data-dynamodb/wiki/Use-Hash-Range-keys

Comment: Very transparently described your path. But indicated exception thrown could be added as stack-trace.

Answer (score 6):

DynamoDB only supports primitive data types, it does not know how to convert your complex field (recentlyPlayedId) into a primitive, such as a String.

To show that this is the case, you can add the annotation @DynamoDBIgnore to your recentlyPlayedId attribute like this:

```
@DynamoDBIgnore
private RecentlyPlayedId recentlyPlayedId;
```

You also need to remove the @id annotation.

Your save function will then work, but the recentlyPlayedId will not be stored in the item. If you do want to save this field, you need to use the @DynamoDBTypeConverted annotation and write a converter class. The converter class defines how to convert the complex field into a String, and then uncovert the String into the complex field.

Comment: Adding the `@DynamoDBIgnore` annotation instead of `@Id` complained that there is no id annotation. Keeping both of them together throws the same error.

Comment: OK, I see you are using a third party library rather DynamoDBMapper. Good luck!

Comment: Hmm. I am using `com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapper`

Comment: @id is not a dynamodbmapper annotation

Comment: Using Spring and DynamoDBMapper together seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Dynamo db mapper definitely supports mapping arbitrary data.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.ArbitraryDataMapping.html

Comment: Which is already included in the answer where I mentioned writing an @DynamoDBTypeConverted class.

Answer (score 3):

Removing getters/setters for the @Id field fixed the problem for me. This is  suggested in  https://github.com/derjust/spring-data-dynamodb/wiki/Use-Hash-Range-keys

Comment: Thank you!  This fixed it for me.  I removed the lombok getter/setter for the @Id field and that solved it

Comment: Thanks, fixed it for me as well, if you're using @Data, exclude id field by @Getter(value=AccessLevel.NONE)
 @Setter(value= AccessLevel.NONE)

Answer (score 0):

not supported; requires @DynamoDBTyped or @DynamoDBTypeConverted",

i was getting this error when i defined model class with field JsonNode,i converted it to MAP<String,String>,now it is working fine